# Django haystack not displaying next months data

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

Django haystack is indexing data but not displaying next months data, i can see data indexed till 30 Nov 2013 23:59:05, but not after that i.e from 01 Dec 2013.

I am using whoosh as my backed and when i delete indexed files and recreate the index, it will start displaying current months data.

Any idea whats wrong happening here ?

-Thanks

Comment: How are you indexing the data? Also, how are you displaying the search results?

Comment: I am using python manage.py update_index and for displaying the search results i am following [this link](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#search-template)